WEN Dust Collector - how to configure Circuit breaker and 5-20r Outlet
I have a WEN Dust collector - rated as 120v, 16amps.
But they say the startup amperage may spike up to 80a for a short moment... ???
the collector has a built-in 25a overload protector, so they say the rating on the fuse must be higher than 25A .....   the power plug/outlet should be NEMA 5-20R.
Does this mean that I need a 30 AMP circuit breaker ?
Is 12 Gauge wiring OK ?   or do i need 10Gauge ??
Can I change out the single 20Amp breaker for a 30AMP breaker..... ( as long as the wiring is 10 gauge ??
Any help or thoughts are appreciated..
steve

I believe you can only use a 20 amp breaker for NEMA 5-20, no larger.  The wire can be larger than 12 gauge, 12 gauge is the minimum for 20 amps.  Most breakers have a delay trip, so high start up amps do not trip them,  I think there are also breakers for motors with a slightly larger trip delay

Thanks !    That is why I'm confused when they say use a NEMA 5-20 outlet but fuse needs to be 25A or more ?????    WEN - chinese company that doesn't care or translation doesn't make sense...   the plug on the Dust Collector is a 5-20r.

If a device has more than one circuit protection, then usually they do not need to be the same size.  The circuit breaker in the panel protects the wires and the outlet.  The dust collector fuse protects the motor.

If it comes with a 5-20p and it is Lab (UL, CSA,ETL) Listed then it must use a 20A breaker. Breakers don't instantly trip. See this graph:

You can see a breaker should hold 4x the rated current (80A in this case) without tripping for 7 to 20 seconds so you should be just fine. The 25A overloads are still needed because 25A  is 125% of a 20A breaker, which should hold for 4 minutes, and could hold indefinitely and still be within NEMA specs. The breaker could also hold 1.5x (30A) for 6 minutes, so 25A overloads would kick in.

Thank you... good info.    the Plug required is a NEMA 5-20R. ( not sure what the difference is to the 5-20P. ?).       Sounds like I use a 20amp fuse at the panel and change outlet to NEMA 5-20R.   this will make it code / safe, but not sure if the breaker will trip constantly....  ??        thank you again...

P indicates (male) Plug, R indicates (female) Receptacle

Welcome to NEC Article 430, motor loads.
These override the "20A=#12" rules at 210.21 and 240.4(D) (just as those rules admit it does).
The reason for amp limits on wires is to prevent wires and devices from overheating and starting a fire in the walls.  Overheating is not instantaneous.  The wires and devices have some thermal mass and can endure a 400% overload for 1 second without undue overheat.  Especially since the device is starting, and that means it was not running, and the wire has had a chance to cool toward ambient.
You see this concept repeated in the Art. 630 welder rules e.g. a 200% overload is permitted if it's for short periods and less than 25% of the time.
The motor spec should name a minimum circuit ampacity - it probably did, 16A.   You must size wire accordingly per Article 430.  I.e. at least #12.
Then it will state a max circuit breaker.
Minimum circuit ampacity <= actual breaker <= max breaker on the label.
